# "invalid operands of types 'objc_object*' and 'float'" error?

Tags: xcode, testing, device

When I try testing my game in xcode simulator I get these errors below. Anyone have an idea what's wrong. Btw the behaivor is for unlocking new levels if actor collides with an object:

> Error in line 49: invalid operands of types 'objc_object*' and 'float'
>   to binary
>
> Error in line 58: invalid operands of types 'objc_object*' and 'float'
>   to binary
>
> Error in line 73 :iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and
>   integer

Here is the IOS code:
Line 49:

```
 if(([mActor touchedActor] && ([self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] >= [self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]])))
```

Line 58:

```
if(([self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] >= [self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]]))
```

Line 73:

```
 if(([mActor touchedActor] && (([self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] <= 5) && [[Game game] purchasedProduct:@"MyID"])))
```

All of the code for the behavior:

```
#import <Box2D/Box2D.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ActorScript.h"

#import "Script.h"

#import "Actor.h"
#import "ActorType.h"
#import "Assets.h"
#import "Behavior.h"
#import "Collision.h"
#import "CollisionPoint.h"
#import "Game.h"
#import "GameModel.h"
#import "GroupDef.h"
#import "FadeInTransition.h"
#import "FadeOutTransition.h"
#import "Region.h"
#import "Runnable.h"
#import "Scene.h"
#import "SHThumbstick.h"
#import "Sparrow.h"
#import "Transition.h"



@interface Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel : ActorScript 
{
    @public
        NSString* tempHolder;

Scene* _Scenetoplay;

NSString* _Levellabel;

float _levelnumber;

}
@end

@implementation Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel

-(void)load
{
        [self addWhenUpdatedListener:nil func:^(NSMutableArray* list, Script* theScript){
Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel* self = (Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel*) theScript;

                    if(([mActor touchedActor] && ([self getGameAttribute:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] floatValue]]]] >= [self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]])))
{
                [self setGameAttribute:[[self getGameAttribute:@"Current Level"] floatValue] value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]]]];
                [self switchScene:_Scenetoplay.ID leave:[self createFadeOut:((1000*1)) color:0] enter:[self createFadeIn:((1000*1)) color:0]];
}

}];
    [self addWhenDrawingListener:nil func:^(SPRenderSupport* g, int x, int y, BOOL screen, NSMutableArray* list, Script* theScript){
Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel* self = (Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel*) theScript;
        if(([self getGameAttribute:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] floatValue]]]] >= [self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]]))
{
            [mActor setAnimation:@"Animation 1"];
            [[Game game] setFont:[ self getFont:52] size:1];
            [[Game game] drawString:_Levellabel x:(([mActor getWidth] - [[Game game] getWidthForString:[ self getFont:52] string:_Levellabel]) / 2) y:30];
}

        else
{
            [mActor setAnimation:@"Animation 0"];
}

}];
    [self addWhenUpdatedListener:nil func:^(NSMutableArray* list, Script* theScript){
Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel* self = (Design_190_190_Clicktoplaylevel*) theScript;
                    if(([mActor touchedActor] && (([self getGameAttribute:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] floatValue]]]] <= [self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5]]) && [[Game game] purchasedProduct:@"MyID"])))
{
                [self setGameAttribute:[[self getGameAttribute:@"Current Level"] floatValue] value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]]]];
                [self switchScene:_Scenetoplay.ID leave:[self createFadeOut:((1000*1)) color:0] enter:[self createFadeIn:((1000*1)) color:0]];
}

            else if((([mActor touchedActor] && [self sameAs:[self getGameAttribute:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] floatValue]]]] two:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5]]]]) && !([[Game game] purchasedProduct:@"MyID"])))
{
                return;
}


}];

} 




-(void)forwardMessage:(NSString*)msg
{
```

Comment: It would be useful if you also posted the source code of the files those errors are referring to.

Comment: Please post your getGameAttribute and asNumber method implementation.

Comment: I do not quite follow what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in all three cases the issue is the same - you are trying to compare `NSNumber` objects. The comparison operators (`<=` & `>=` in your case) are not overloaded to accept `NSNumber`.

`NSNumber` itself has three methods: `isEqualToNumber:`, `isEqual:`, and `compare:`; which will compare two `NSNumber` instances.

You can also compare the value of the `NSNumber` using `floatValue`, `inValue`, *et al*. So for example your last comparison could be:

```
[self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"].intValue <= 5
```

or using method, instead of property, syntax:

```
[[self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] intValue] <= 5
```

BTW You appear to have your game level stored as a floating point number. I obviously don't know your application, but storing it as an integer would seem both more logical and avoid an issues with floating point rounding (depending on the operations you perform on them).

Comment: thank you this helped a lot. I've fixed two of them 58 & 73 but somehow I still get the error in line 49. Could you show me how you would fix this (line 49) ?                                      :  if(([mActor touchedActor] && ([self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] >= [self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]])))

Comment: @user2422226 - The comparison in 49 is the same as the one in 58, so the changes required should be the same. Your expr `[self asNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_levelnumber]]` *looks* strange. It takes a floating point number (strange in itself, see the BTW in answer), constructs an `NSNumber` object from it and then passes it to a method which returns an `NSNumber` object... What does `asNumber` do & why are you using all these `NSNumber` objects in the first place? These q's cannot be answered from the code shown. I think you might be confused over the use & need for `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the qucik reply and yes I am a bit confused by NSNumber objects also I'm new to objective-c. The BTW is noted (will do from now on but I'm all most finished with this game so will not do it until Next one). I actually discovered that 58 wasn't working propperly this is the code line 58  :                                                              `if(([self getGameAttribute:@"Highest Level Completed"] >= [self asNumber:[floatValue:_levelnumber]))))´

Comment: @user2422226 - If you haven't changed it then of course it won't work, that is what the answer explains - you cannot compare `NSNumber` objects with comparison operators (from the error message you are trying to compare an `NSNumber` and a `float`). Objective-C, being in the C family, provides plenty of scope for the programmer to write stuff which is accepted by the compiler but meaningless. You're lucky the compiler has flagged these 3, they're too wrong even for C. However if elsewhere you are comparing, for example, two `NSNumber`s then the compiler may well be quiet but the result wrong.